# PHP Start Background Scripts in Windows without waiting for completion

Tags: php

Ok So I have a PHP file where once a file is uploaded it is moved to a new location this triggers an event to let the user know that the file has been uploaded and starts a conversion process of the PDF file they have submitted.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
echo '{"status":"success"}';
echo 'File Uploaded';
include('tools/convert.php');
exit;
}
```

This causes the page to hang whilst the convert.php file runs.
I have looked over Google for different ways to get a PHP script to run in the background.
Here is a list of some of the scripts I have tried:-

```
/* Attempt 1 Command Line */
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
echo '{"status":"success"}';
echo 'File Uploaded';
exec("C:/php/php5/php.exe tools/convert.php")  
exit;
}

/* Attempt 2 Session Closing within convert.php */
ob_start();
session_start();
session_write_close();
ob_end_flush();

/* Attempt 3 Session Closing */
session_start();
session_unlink();
session_destroy();
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
header("Location: tools/convert.php");
```

I not to sure about running a cron for this as this script needs to be run only once a file has been uploaded and not on a schedule and the files are uploaded to different locations depending on the user.

And many other variations of these and other scripts, How am I able to run the first code to exit() but have the tool/convert.php file still running?

I am using:-
Windows Server 2008 R2
IIS 7
PHP 5.2.17

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: The session is completely unrelated to executed applications. Write your jobs in a database and have a background daemon looking for new jobs in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run CRON for that any other function will get call when the operation perform.

OR

You can use the Ajax in you code

Comment: Could you provide a full answer, or post as a comment? When you post an answer it shows in the list of questions and other people who could give a proper answer are likely to skip the question because it appears to have an answer.

Comment: I ended up creating a cron job pointing at a PHP file which runs every 5 min to see if there is any data inside a database. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Session is unrelated. To keep the process running after the user closes a page, include this code before the procedure

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP will wait for its child process to finish executing when using exec. You need to redirect the output and detach it. As you are running on windows it can be done like this:

```
<?php 
$shell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$shell->run("C:/php/php5/php.exe tools/convert.php", 0, false); //Need the full path to your convert script
```

Comment: I have attempted to do this by using the following:-  

    $shell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
    $shell->run("C:/Program Files (x86)/Parallels/Plesk/Additional/Plesk/PHP5/php.exe C:/inetpub/vhost/site/site.co.uk/$user/tools/convert.php", 0, false);  

But it doesn't work?
I have specified the $user in the header.